# UICollectionView nested in a UIScrollView loads all cells at once

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a few very long collectionViews, all nested inside a scrollView.
since the prefetching range is related to the scrollView, all the cells are "visible" on the scrollView, even though most of them are not visible on the screen at all.
Hence, when calling reloadData(), it reloads all the cells, instead of reloading only the visible cells. it ends up in a very long UI freeze.

Is there a way to load only the cells that are truly visible on the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way to do this is to put everything inside a UITableView which has UICollectionViews as cells. It sounds horrible (and tbh, its not very nice) but it's really the only "clean" way to do this.

Let the UITableView act as the ScrollView and everything else should work just fine, it should, all in all, be much faster and shouldn't lock up the UI.

Comment: Thanks! Then - the "visible" collectionView cells will be calculated according to the UITableViewCell, which means that even if only one cell is visible on the screen, the whole collectionView inside it will be loaded, and not only the visible cells. Am I right? If so, it's not good enough for me: even one collectionView is to long to be loaded all at once.